# How do import package from fragment to plugin

Tags: java, plugins, import, fragment

In my application I have a plugin that has a file in a package that tries to import a package that exists in another fragment but with no success.
I've tried to update the exported packages in the fragment and then import the package in the plugin but have had no success.
Please advice.

Comment: Could you add some source code?

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to add 
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true to the fragment host. 
Note that this is a pure-tooling header used by PDE, not an Eclipse or OSGi runtime header.

See [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/bundle_manifest.html).